how to call Java args @-file from a batch file
I am trying to run the following batch file to launch a Minecraft server.
run.bat
@echo off
REM Forge requires a configured set of both JVM and program arguments.
REM Add custom JVM arguments to the user_jvm_args.txt
REM Add custom program arguments {such as nogui} to this file in the next line before the %* or
REM  pass them to this script directly
java -Xmx4G @libraries\net\neoforged\neoforge\21.1.37\win_args.txt %*
pause


the batch file just calls
java -Xmx4G @libraries\net\neoforged\neoforge\21.1.37\win_args.txt %*
and gives me this error
Error: Could not find or load main class 
@libraries\net\neoforged\neoforge\21.1.37\win_args.txt

the files does exist and I am able to start the server fine if I run this command manually in command prompt
so why does the batch file have trouble with the @-file?
running with java 21

I did not write this file, this is what is generated with Minecraft mod server loader. I got the file from here https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/enigmatica10/files/5701685/additional-files

I do not have a Windows environment at hand, so I did not tested my suggestions below.
Have you tried:
@echo off
REM Forge requires a configured set of both JVM and program arguments.
REM Add custom JVM arguments to the user_jvm_args.txt
REM Add custom program arguments {such as nogui} to this file in the next line before the %* or
REM  pass them to this script directly
"java -Xmx4G @libraries\net\neoforged\neoforge\21.1.37\win_args.txt %*"
pause

or
@echo off
REM Forge requires a configured set of both JVM and program arguments.
REM Add custom JVM arguments to the user_jvm_args.txt
REM Add custom program arguments {such as nogui} to this file in the next line before the %* or
REM  pass them to this script directly
java -Xmx4G "@libraries\net\neoforged\neoforge\21.1.37\win_args.txt" %*
pause

Inside a Windows batch file, the @ has a special meaning, while it does not have that meaning on the command line. So masking or escaping it somehow should do the job.

I tried your second suggestion and did not work will try the first one. I tied adding / infront of @ thinking it needed to be escapped as well but could not figure it out.

no neither of those work.
